# How to "select where" within json in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, select, oracle12c

I have a table called DISCOUNT_CODES with two columns, one having JSON values:

```
CODE           ACTIVE
1234           {"active":"Y"}
2468           {"active":"N"}
1359           {"active":"Y"}
```

As the second column is in JSON, I was wondering if there was a way I can select the codes that are active without having to do a select query like:

```
SELECT CODE FROM DISCOUNT_CODES WHERE ACTIVE = '{"active":"Y"}';
```

In pseudo-code, I am wondering if something like this is possible:

```
SELECT CODE FROM DISCOUNT_CODES WHERE JSON(ACTIVE $.active) = "Y";
```

Edit: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: what version db do you have? the native JSON() support in Oracle starts with 12c, before that you might need a helper package (APEX has one for example)

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a SELECT statement containing `JSON_TABLE()` function for the DB version 12c+ such as the one below :

```
SELECT d.code
  FROM discount_codes d
 CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(active, '$' COLUMNS (
                                            active VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.active'
                                           )
                      ) j
 WHERE j.active = 'Y'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ab4b31697fc7ae5df2f92f216ca2a02)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `JSON_EXISTS`

```
SELECT CODE FROM DISCOUNT_CODES
WHERE json_exists(ACTIVE, '$?(@.active == "Y")');
```